# Android studio missing git widget

Tags: git, android-studio

I'm running Android studio 2.0 preview 5, and my GIT widget is missing. It's supposed to show my current branch and quick actions for branches down at the bottom right of the IDE. I've checked other people running the same version of AS, and they have it in place. See my screenshot below. Does anyone know how to bring it back?

How it is supposed to be:

[image: Git widget]

My bar:

[image: Missing git widget]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please go to Settings | Version Control and make sure that the Git integration is enabled for your project. You also need to enable the status bar (View | Status Bar).

Comment: Ah, my god. Thank you very much. The status bar was missing. Now I feel stupid.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the Git branch is enabled in the status bar widgets.

View -> Appearnce -> Status bar widgets -> Git Branch

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was unregistered root in Version Control menu
[image]